# Descriptions for type fields in graphiql not showing

Tags: node.js, express, graphql, apollo-server, graphiql

For reference, I'm using `graphql-tools` to build my schema and `apollo-server-express` to provide the graphiql interface.

In graphiql, the following schema is only showing the description for Query and not for the user field. I've also tried using the `"""` syntax shown in the [apollo docs](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/graphql-tools/generate-schema.html#descriptions) but that didn't work either.

What could be causing the description for Query to show but not for the inner field?

```
# Description for Query
type Query {
  # Returns data for a single user.
  user(id: Int): User
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The way I was attempting was the correct way.

```
# Single line field description

"""
Multiple
line description
"""
```

---

The problem I was *actually* having was that my dev server wasn't automatically restarting.

I wrote my schema definitions using multiple plaintext `.gql` files (for syntax highlighting) and didn't realize that those files weren't being watched by `nodemon`.

I just needed to define what file extensions to watch by adding the `ext` line to the nodemon config in my `package.json` file:

```
"nodemonConfig": {
  "watch": ["src/"],
  "ext": "js json gql"
},
```